# Solving a differential equation for a variable in a function

Tags: equation-solving, functions, differential-equations, system-variables

This may sound like a very trivial question, but I need to solve a differential equation as follows:

```
a := 3.24077*10^-20 (* km \[Rule] Mpc *)
b := 3.16888*10^-14 (* s \[Rule] MYear *)
c := a/b*(2.99792*10^5) (*Mpc/ MYear*)
\[HBar] := a^2/b (1.05457*10^-37)(*kgMpc^2/MYear*)
H0 := a/b*71 (*1/MYear*)
G := a^3/b^2*6.67398*10^-20 (*Mpc^3/(Kg*MYear^2)*)
\[CapitalOmega]M := 0.27
\[CapitalOmega]\[Gamma] := 8.24*10^-4
\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda] := 0.73
\[Lambda] := 1/a^2 1*10^-58(*1/Mpc^2*)
f := 1*10^-4
y := 10
\[Rho]pert[r_] := \[Rho]*(1 + f*Exp[-(r/y)^2]) // N
M2[r_] := 4 \[Pi]*Integrate[\[Rho]pert[r1]*(r1)^2, r1] /. r1 -> r
E2[r_] := 
 1/2*((H[999]*r)/(c*(1000)))^2 - ((G *M2[r] (1000))/(
   c^2 (r))) - (\[Lambda]*r^2)/(3 (1000)^2)
ScaleFactor2 = 
 NDSolve[SetPrecision[{(D[R2[r, t], t]) == 
     Sqrt[(2*G*M2[r])/R2[r, t] + 2*c^2*E2[r] + (
      2 c^2 \[Lambda]*R2[r, t]^2)/3], R2[r, 0] == r/1000}, 200], 
  R2, {r, 1, 20000}, {t, 1, 15000}, AccuracyGoal -> 2]
Rad2[r_, t_] := Evaluate[R2[r, t] /. ScaleFactor2]
RadPrime2[r_, t_] := D[Rad2[r1, t], r1] /. r1 ->  r
Raddot2[r_, t_] := D[Rad2[r, t], t]
***chi = DSolve[(c Sqrt[1 + 2 E2[r]])/RadPrime2[r, t], r, t]***
```

I am looking for a solution for the differential equation chi, but would like an answer whose subject is the variable *r* that appears in `RadPrime2[r,t]`. In other words, I am looking for the functional form of r(t)...

I apologise in advance if this seems really badly phrased and/or trivial, but I couldn't find anything in the literature that helped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constitutes only a beginning (if that) of an answer, maybe more an extended comment.  You seem to have some problems with your code. First, I don't think you need to define any of the following as functions (i.e., defined using `:=` ):

```
a, b, c, \[HBar], H0, G, \[CapitalOmega]M, \[CapitalOmega]\[Gamma], \
\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda], \[Lambda], f, y
```

A simple `=` ought to work fine for these as you don't pass them any inputs.

In your function `E2[r_]` you appear to have an undefined function, which you supply with an input: `H[999]`.  What do you intend `H[]` to return?

In `ScaleFactor2` you use another function `R2[r,t]` that you have not defined.

You use `R2[r,t]` again in `Rad2[]`

I haven't thought through all of it but I also suggest you look at your uses of the following:

`\[Rho]` in `\[Rho]pert`

`r1` in `M2[r_]`

`r` in the `DSolve`

I then suggest you methodically run the code line by line and determine where the problem(s) starts.

Update you question or clarify any of this in comments.  It will make it easier to help you.